# Is my proof that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\sin\frac{1}{x}=0$ correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

I tried to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\sin\frac{1}{x}$$

And I arrived at the answer that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\sin\frac{1}{x}=0$. Is my solution correct?

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\sin\frac{1}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\frac{1}{x}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t}$

And as $\frac{-1}{t}\leq \frac{\sin t}{t}\leq \frac{1}{t}$ for all $t>0$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{-1}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{t}=0$ then by Squeeze theorem we get $\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t}=0$.

Is it correct? Is there a quicker, smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not complete, because you only have computed
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\sin\frac{1}{x}
$$
and you should also do the limit from the left; however, as $\sin(-\alpha)=-\sin\alpha$, the function is even, so the limit from the left is equal to the limit from the right, provided one of them exists.

Your substitution, however, just exploits the fact that $|\sin\alpha|\le1$ and you can use this fact to begin with:
$$
-|x|\le x\sin\frac{1}{x}\le |x|
$$
and the squeeze theorem immediately provides you the limit.

Answer (score 13):

Yes correct but simply you can do

$$0\le \left|x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right|\le|x|$$
and use the squeeze thorem.

Answer (score 6):

here is a slightly quicker way. take the inequality $-1 \le \sin \dfrac{1}{x} \le 1$ 
this gives $$ -|x| \le x\sin \dfrac{1}{x} \le |x|$$ now use the squeeze theorem.